# Classical mechanics principle of least action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I don't understand here what does the book mean by expanding in terms of $\delta{q}$ and $\delta{\dot{q}}$ can someone explain that part.
[image]

Comment: It is just point-wise Taylor expansion of the function $L$. That is $L(q+\delta q, \dot q + \delta \dot q, t) \approx L(q, \dot q, t) + \delta q \partial_q L(q, \dot q, t) + \delta \dot q \partial_{\dot q} L(q, \dot q, t) + \ldots$, and $q$ and $\dot q$ are considered independent quantities.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: That's an answer ;)

Comment: Ok I got it thank you here we must see that q and $\dot{q}$ are indepedent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just point-wise Taylor expansion of the function $L$ in the integrand. That is 
$$L(q+\delta q, \dot q + \delta \dot q, t) \approx L(q, \dot q, t) + \delta q \partial_q L(q, \dot q, t) + \delta \dot q \partial_{\dot q} L(q, \dot q, t) + \ldots, $$
where $q$ and $\dot q$ are considered independent quantities.

Comment: just one question when we expand using taylor expansion the reason we don't include the $\delta{q}$ term is because we expanded in terms of it ? i.e we evalaute $\delta{q}$ to zero right ?